# Models like "MyModel" (2 words) does not load

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have created an example model:

```
class ExampleModel extends Eloquent {
   protected $table = 'example_model';
}
```

Then I tried to call `ExampleModel::all()` which returned an error `function all() does not exist` (seems like the class is created but without Eloquent functions). After changing model name (and file name) to `Examplemodel` (now the model name is one word) it works. The problem is not that I misspelled something as I have checked that like a hundred of times and my file+class names are matching.

Am I missing something about auto loading?

I am on windows so I also tried changing file's name to `Examplemodel` without changing the class name but it still seems to load the class without `Eloquent` methods.

Comment: Have you checked the file name of model class?It should be same as the class name mentioned.

Comment: @Infinity Yes, I have even copy&pasted in case I missed some letter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a problem. I had a migration with class same as my model. Laravel is auto loading models with migrations and it thought I was referring to migration instead of a model.

After fixing that of course I had to run `dumpautoload` composer command.

Answer (score 1):

Did you do **Autoload (dumpautoload)**?

Because of this case works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Do composer dump-autoload
As the following works for me:

```
class ExampleTest extends \Eloquent {
protected $table = 'users';
```

}

Then on the routes file I have:

```
Route::get('/', function()
{
    $data = ExampleTest::all();

    return $data;

});
```

This gives me the data from my users table.

Answer (score 0):

create a file example.php in models folder and then write this:

```
class Example extends Eloquent {
    protected $table = 'example_model';
}
```

and then try:

```
Example::all();
```

taken from [here](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent)

Comment: Yes, this will work. The thing is I need several models that start with `History`, like HistoryXxx, HistoryYyy, HistoryZzz.

Comment: happy to help somehow